# finite loop breaks in an unusal way+image

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

everything of this code seems regular

it is going to take numbers continuously till get zero

then type em of last to first without putting zero as its first number

but when i reach to put  10th number, program finishes! i also checked it via debug but shows nothing
in fact according to debugger when program returns to  **"while(rna==1){"** in first lines for 10th number, next step should be **cin>>10th number** but program Finishes

i should notify that i put breakpoints on 5th, 10th, 13th, 18th lines for debugger

quest & result:

```
1

2

3

4

5

0

answer:

5

4

3

2

1
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int rna=1;
  int t=0,x,xinverse[t]={};
  
  while(rna==1){
    cin>>x;
    xinverse[t]=x;

    if(x==0)
      rna=0;
    else
      t=t+1;
  }

  if(t<=999){
  
    while(rna==0 && t>=1){ 
      cout<<xinverse[t-1]<<endl;
      if(t==1)
        rna=1;
      else
        t=t-1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `int t=0,x,xinverse[x]={};`, what is the value of `x`?  How big of an array is `xinverse` going to be?

Comment: Very _undefined behavior_ at `x,xinverse[x]={}`

Comment: Is anyone supposed to read this code? The intendation causes more confusion than it adds to readability here.

Comment: @NathanOliver thx i edited xinverse[t] in question and checked again but nothing changes

Comment: `int t=0,x,xinverse[t]={};` (a) should not compile and (b) is an array with no elements. live - https://godbolt.org/z/qrdfbbEEY

Comment: @میمشین What is the value of `t`?  What does it mean to have an array with that size?  How many elements will be in that array?

Comment: Dear @NathanOliver program starts with xinverse[t=0] then get number and save it in this array t=0 then if x wasnt equal to 0 add t++ and start again the loop

Comment: You need an array, `xinverse`, big enough to hold the numbers that come as input. To achieve that, you can either allocate initially a big array, and hope the user does not try to give more numbers, or limit the amount of numbers you will accept from the user.

The other approach is to ask the user how many numbers they want to give as input, then allocate an array of the corresponding size

Comment: thx @zios  i try this

Comment: As a suggestion for code clarity, in c++ you can use the type `bool`. Specifically, for `rna`, you are using it as a logical variable, only values `0` and `1`. It might add clarity to change that variable to a `bool`.

Comment: @میمشین Try to answer the questions asked by NathanOliver, it might help you clarify what is wrong with the array allocation as it is in the code you shared.